# What if the class is not working properly when i make it into a function and apply it to Swagger's response in NestJS?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Please understand that my English is very poor.

Example Code : [Github](https://github.com/ordidxzero/nest-interceptor-question)

```js
@Injectable()
export class FAQService {
  constructor(private faqRepository: FAQRepository) {}

  async getFAQ(options: Options): Promise<GetFAQResponse> {
    const response = await paginate<FAQEntity>(this.faqRepository, options);
    return { data: response, statusCode: 200 };
  }
}
```

In the project we are working on, the shape of the return value is set as `{data: response, statusCode: 200}`, as shown in the method above.
This form was repeated in all services of all modules, and when `response` was returned from the service method, the interceptor changed to make it `{data: response, statusCode: 200}`.
Here, I have a problem that if the interceptor performs the corresponding processing, it does not apply to swagger.
To solve this problem, I created a custom decorator as follows.

```js
// http-method.decorator.ts
import { ApiOkResponse, ApiOperation, ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Get as NestGet, applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';

class BaseResponse {
  @ApiProperty()
  data: any;

  @ApiProperty()
  statusCode: number;
}

export interface IEndpointParams {
  route: string;
  summary: string;
  type?: Type<unknown> | Function | [Function] | string;
}

const mapResponse = <T>(type: T) => {
  class Response extends BaseResponse {
    @ApiProperty({ type })
    data: T;
  }
  return Response;
};

export function Get(params: IEndpointParams) {
  const { route, summary, type } = params;
  return applyDecorators(NestGet(route), ApiOperation({ summary }), ApiOkResponse({ type: mapResponse(type) }));
}
```

It was applied to the controller as below.

```js
@Controller('faq')
@ApiTags('FAQ API')
@ApiSecurity('Authorization')
export class FAQController {
  constructor(private faqService: FAQService) {}

  @Get({ route: '', summary: 'List Of FAQ', type: GetFAQResponse })
  async faqs(@PaginationQuery() query: PaginationQuery): Promise<GetFAQResponse> {
    return await this.faqService.getFAQ(query);
  }
}
```

And I created an interceptor and applied it to the app.

```js
// http-response.interceptor.ts
@Injectable()
export class HttpResponseInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<BaseResponse> {
    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    return next.handle().pipe(map((data) => ({ data, statusCode: response.statusCode })));
  }
}

// app.module.ts
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';
...
import { HttpResponseInterceptor } from './common/http-response.interceptor';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...
    FaqModule,
    TradeModule,
    BannersModule,
    NoticeModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RolesGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: HttpExceptionFilter,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: HttpResponseInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  ...
}
```

As above, the swagger also shows the `{data: response, statusCode: 200}`, but the problem is that all endpoints in the swagger were applied the type that was last method of the controller of last imported module in `AppModule` (here, `NoticeModule`).

```js
// faq.controller.ts
@Controller('faq')
@ApiTags('FAQ API')
@ApiSecurity('Authorization')
export class FAQController {
  constructor(private faqService: FAQService) {}

  @Get({ route: '', summary: 'List Of FAQ', type: GetFAQResponse })
  async faqs(@PaginationQuery() query: PaginationQuery): Promise<GetFAQResponse> {
    return await this.faqService.getFAQ(query);
  }
}

// notice.controller.ts
@Controller('notice')
@ApiTags('Notice API')
@ApiSecurity('Authorization')
export class NoticeController {
  constructor(private noticeService: NoticeService) {}

  @Get({ route: '', summary: 'List Of FAQ', type: GetNoticeResponse })
  async notices(@PaginationQuery() query: PaginationQuery): Promise<GetNoticeResponse> {
    return await this.noticeService.getNotice(query);
  }
}
```

Suppose that `FAQ Controller` and `Notice Controller` are as described above. Now that `Notice Module` is last imported in `AppModule`, `GetNoticeResponse` is reflected in the swagger document of faq endpoint, not `GetFAQResponse`. The problem seems to be occurring in the `mapResponse` function, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer.

The name of the class generated through the `mapResponse` function overlapped and the last class was reflected at Swagger.

So, the code was modified as below to prevent overlapping names.

```js
const mapResponse = <T>(type: T) => {
  if (!type) return type;
  const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(type, 'name');
  class WrappedResponse extends BaseResponse {
    @ApiProperty({ type })
    data: T;
  }
  Object.defineProperty(WrappedResponse, 'name', {
    value: `Wrapped${descriptor.value}`,
  });
  return WrappedResponse;
};
```